# Neo4j randomly high CPU

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j 3.5.12 Community Edition
Ubuntu Server 20.04.2
RAM: 32 Gb
EC2 instance with 4 or 8 CPUs (I change it to accommodate for processing at the moment)
Database files: 6.5Gb
Python, WSGI, Flask

dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=17g
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=17g
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=11g

I'm seeing high CPU use on the server in what appears to be a random pattern.  I've profiled all the queries for the pages that I know that people are visiting at those times and they are all optimised with executions under 50ms in all cases.  The CPU use doesn't seem linked with user numbers which are very low at most times anyway (max 40 concurrent users). I've checked all queries in cron jobs too.

I reduced the database notes significantly and that made no difference to performance.

I warm the database by preloading all nodes into ram with `MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]->() RETURN count(n.prop) + count(r.prop);`

The pattern is that there will be a few minutes of very low CPU use (as I would expect from this setup with these user numbers) and then processing on most CPU cores goes up to the high 90%s and the machine becomes unresponsive to new requests.  Changing to an 8CPU instance sorts it, but shouldn't be needed for this level of traffic.

[image]

I would like to profile the queries with query logging, but the community edition doesn't support that.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the debug.log. My gut feeling is that the JVM triggered a garbage collection.

Comment: Yes that was my thought too.  It just seems to be rather a lot more than I would expect to see.

Answer (score 1):

Run a CPU profiler such as [`perf`](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) to record where CPU time is spent. You can then visualize it as a [FlameGraph](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html) or, since your bursts only occur at random intervals, visualize it over time with Netflix' [FlameScope](https://github.com/Netflix/flamescope)

Since Neo4j is a Java application, it might also be worthwhile to have a look at [`async-profiler`](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) which is priceless when it comes to profiling Java applications (and it generates similar FlameGraphs and can output log files compatible with FlameScope or JMC)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look at these options.